# How to compare session variable with URL value

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on an admin panel and admin divides tasks among various users so i want specific users to use specific pages only which they are permitted to use (all other page's links should not be clickable).

I am passing a unique page ID with every page's URL and the page's IDs to which users are permitted to use are stored in database so I need to compare my session variable with URL value, in session variable i am fetching page's id to which user are permitted to use.

I am trying this code but getting no success

```
if (isset($_SESSION['pageID']) && isset($_GET['page'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['pageID'] == (int)$_GET['page']){
        // Proceeding code 
    }
    else {
        // return fail
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated as i spent hours working on this.
   Thanks in advance !

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION['pageID'])` and check what you are getting.

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code? What's in the $_SESSION and have you used session_start() at the beginning? Cheers!

Comment: Yes sessions are started.
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['pageid']) && isset($_GET['page']))
    {
    if($_SESSION['pageid'] == (int)$_GET['page'])
 {
   // proceeding code 
 }
        else { // fail }
  }

Comment: What's the value of $_SESSION['pageid'] and $_GET['page']? From your code everything seems fine, but I can not tell without the data.

Comment: What are the two values?

Comment: Both contains page id. Like page link is /add_user.php?page=1 so 1 is page id which i am getting from $_GET['page'] and if user is permitted to this page then this id will store in database and in session i am getting this page id

Comment: Both contains page id. Like page link is /add_user.php?page=1 so 1 is page id which i am getting from $_GET['page'] and if user is permitted to this page then this id will store in database and in session i am getting this page id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the roles in the database not in the session. In a roles table you can store the privileges of users. For instance you can say that this kind of users shall access this page id. Once you created this when user wants to access your page you should send a query to your table to learn if this user have access to this specific page.

Example pseudo code:

```
$available_pages_for_user = select * from table_roles where user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']
if $_GET['page'] in $available_pages_for_user
    //Proceed
else
    //401 error or smt..
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['pageID']) && isset($_GET['page'])) {

    $s = $_SESSION['pageID'];  //check what is coming
    $p = $_GET['page'];
    if ($s == $p){
        // Proceeding code 
    }
    else {
        // return fail
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows blank page when i store $_SESSION['pageID'] and $_GET['page'] in variables.